# is it possible to avoid using Wi-Fi Direct when communicating with Nearby Connections?

Tags: android, bluetooth, google-nearby

Is it possible to either only use BLE with Nearby Connections or somehow do not switch to the WiFi direct network that Nearby Connection creates?

For my problem, I'm using the P2P_STAR strategy and it is not possible to disconnect all the "clients" from the internet while using the Nearby Connections.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use P2P_CLUSTER. It uses slower, less disruptive mediums.